# Read Excel file and skip empty rows but not empty columns

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I wish to read an Excel file and skip the empty rows. My code skips empty cells but it skips empty columns, too. How can I skip empty rows but maintain empty columns? I'm using JXL Java.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
        Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
        String con = cell.getContents();
        if (con != null && con.length() != 0) {          
            System.out.print(con);
            System.out.print("|");
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, try apache poi. Still has support, not sure if jxl does

Comment: So there's no way I could do this using JXL?

Comment: I'm sure you can, but poi allows more control regarding your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
    boolean rowEmpty = true;
    String currentRow = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
        Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
        String con=cell.getContents();
        if(con !=null && con.length()!=0){
            rowEmpty = false;
        }
        currentRow += con + "|";
    }
    if(!rowEmpty) {
        System.out.println(currentRow);
    }
}
```

What you were doing is:

- Loop through rows

  - Loop through columns

    - Print cell if it's empty only, skip it otherwise (your continue statement does nothing as it's the last instruction in the loop anyway, and a break statement would just stop reading the row once it reaches an empty cell)

What this does is:

- Loop through rows

  - Loop through columns

    - Append the cell to the row's string, and if it's non-empty then set rowEmpty to false (as it contains at least one non-empty cell)
  - Print the row only if it's not empty

Answer (score 0):

In case of C#, This works for me

```
private bool CheckIfEmptyRow(ISheet worksheet, int rowIndex)
{
    var worksheetRow = worksheet.GetRow(rowIndex);
    bool isRowEmpty = true;
    for (var columnIndex = worksheetRow.FirstCellNum; columnIndex < worksheetRow.LastCellNum; columnIndex++)
    {
        ICell cell = worksheetRow.GetCell(columnIndex, MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.StringCellValue))
        {
            isRowEmpty = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isRowEmpty;
}
```